# Adding an autocomplete for search

Tags: discussion, search

Has autocompletion been discussed for the search at the top right of a stackexchange sight? I'm relatively new to stackexchange in that my oldest account is 5 months old, so I am not sure if this has been suggested before.

This feature would seem to be useful for physics, since we are often typing the same words into search, i.e. "Feynman path integral" "covering group" etc. Additionally an autocomplete feature for search might be of aid to beginning users of the sight (beginning physics exploration), who might not know what to query.

I am not sure how the task of subdividing the code to build the autocompletion would go, but that seems secondary right now.

The **main question** is whether users of the sight would find the feature of autocompletion for search useful.

Comment: It probably has come up on [metaSO].

Comment: Ahh did not know that existed, thanks.

Comment: Here is the link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29277/